# How to pass a class-element of an ArrayList type on to a method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, types

How would I pass an element of an ArrayList type on to a method? My naive attempt goes along the lines below.

```
public double example( ArrayList<CMyType> list, String type ){

    double out = list.get(0).type // type should be a placeholder for one of the variables which I defined in CMyType
    return out;

}

public class CMyType {
    public double var1;
    public double var2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do here:

```
double out = list.get(0).type // type should be a placeholder for one of
```

is not possible without the use of reflection, like this:

```
public double example( ArrayList<CMyType> list, String type ) {
  CMyClass obj = list.get(0);
  Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(type);
  Object objOut = field.get(obj);
  // you could check for null just in case here
  double out = (Double) objOut;
  return out;
}
```

You can also consider on modifying your `CMyType` class to look like this:

```
class CMyType {
  private double var1;
  private double var2;

  public double get(String type) {
    if ( type.equals("var1") ) {
      return var1;
    } 
    if ( type.equals("var2") ) {
      return var2;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

and then call it from your code like this:

```
public double example( ArrayList<CMyType> list, String type ) {
  CMyClass myobj = list.get(0);
  return myobj.get(type);
}
```

Even better solution would be to use `Map<String, Double>` in `CMyType` like this:

```
class CMyType {
  private Map<String, Double> vars = new HashMap();

  public CMyType() {
    vars.put("var1", 0.0);
    vars.put("var2", 0.0);
  }

  public double get(String type) {
    Double res = vars.get(type);
    if ( res == null ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
public double example( ArrayList<CMyType> list, String type ){
    double out = list.get(0).type // type should be a placeholder for one of the variables which I defined in CMyType
    return out;
}

public class CMyType {
    public double var1;
    public double var2;
}

public invocationTest() {
   ArrayList<CMyType> arrayList = new ArrayList<CMyType>(); //or populate it somehow
   return myExample(arrayList.get(0));
}

public double myExample( CMyType member, String type ){
    double out = member.type;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: i think that he wants to use `type` as field name for `CMyType` field

Comment: Ah, then he needs to use reflection to access the member by a String type.